# Android Event.START_DATE Format

Tags: android, date-format, android-contacts

The format for Event.START_DATE for storing events in contact will be same across different devices(HTC, Samsung, LG, Sony Ericsson, etc.,) or will it differ? If it differs, is there any way to determine the format used by those manufacturers?

Comment: I asked this on Motorola's forum (seems like newer Motorola phones are the only ones using a long instead of YYYY-MM-DD). They said they'll check with the Motodev team and get back to me.

Comment: Thanks EboMike.... Please let me know if you get any reply from Motorola forum.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per sqlite's datatype link http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. The format of the Event.START_DATE will be in one of the following three format.

> 1. TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> 2. REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich
>      on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to
>      the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> 3. INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates
>   and times in any of these formats and
>   freely convert between formats using
>   the built-in date and time functions.

Answer (score 0):

i used the next format:

```
private static final DateFormat BIRTHDATE_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
...
final String dateStr = BIRTHDATE_FORMATTER.format(eventDate);
```